# Service Fabric Actor Service using ReliableStateManager

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'd like to create a ReliableStateManager in a custom ActorService in order to create secondary indices but receiving a null reference exception.

Is it possible to create a ReliableStateManager in a custom ActorService?

```
    class MyActorService : ActorService
    {
        private IReliableStateManager _stateManager;

        public MyActorService(StatefulServiceContext context, ActorTypeInformation typeInfo)
            : base(context, typeInfo)
        {
            _stateManager = new ReliableStateManager(context);
        }

        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // error thrown here
            var d = await _stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<F>("test");
        }
    }

    public class F : IReliableState
    {
        public Uri Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a separate service to store your data and use SF remoting to query it. Your approach is not how the programming model is supposed to be used.